# Calculator that is part of a multipurpose program

Tags: python, calculator

I am currently working on a Python project.  It is some sort of a hub, where you can do some cool but basic stuff, such as: setting timers, launching websites, doing basic math, ping and view source codes of URLs, and more.

I want to make this code just a little more compact. I especially want my math menu more compact because I feel there is a way of doing it.  I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
…
elif userIn == ("math"):
    op = str(input("    * Enter operation (+, -, *, /, exp, sqrt, log): "))
    blank()
    if op==("+") or op==("-") or op==("*") or op==("/") or op==("exp"):
        input_1 = int(input("       * Enter first number:  "))
        blank()
        input_2 = int(input("       * Enter second number: "))
        blank()
    if op == ("+"):
        print ("       > "+str(input_1 + input_2))
        blank()
    elif op == ("-"):
        print ("       > "+str(input_1-input_2))
        blank()
    elif op == ("*"):
        print ("       > "+str(input_1*input_2))
        blank()
    elif op == ("/"):
        print ("       > "+str(input_1/input_2))
        blank()
    elif op == ("exp"):
        print ("       > "+str(input_1**input_2))
        blank()
    elif op == ("sqrt"):
        oneInput=int(input("        * Enter number: "))
        blank()
        print ("       > "+str(math.sqrt(oneInput)))
        blank()
    elif op == ("log"):
        input_1 = int(input("       * Enter number:  "))
        blank()
        input_2 = int(input("       * Enter base: "))
        blank()
        print ("       > "+str(int((math.log(input_1, input_2)))))
        blank()
```

[Link to the code (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/pEqvvaLZ).

Note: I have tried setting a basic for loop run through a list of operation symbols, and it would set the operation if the user op. was matched.  But, as it turns out, I just couldn't use strings as math operators in the code itself.

```
opl=["+", "-", "*", "/"]
for i in range(len(opl)):
    userInput1 (some way of setting op)     userInput2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `dict` as switch-statement like structure.

First some global helper functions/data structures:

```
math_dict_binary = {'+': lambda a, b: a+b,
                    '-': lambda a, b: a-b,
                    # fill out the rest of you binary functions
                   }
math_dict_uniary = {'sqrt': math.sqrt,
                    # rest of you uniary
                   }


def get_input(str_prompt):
    input = int(input("       * {}:  ".format(str_prompt)))
    blank()
    return input
```

in your main body:

```
elif userIn == ("math"):
    op = str(input("    * Enter operation (+, -, *, /, exp, sqrt, log): "))
    blank()
    if op in math_dict_binary:
        input_1 = get_input("Enter first number")
        input_2 = get_input("Enter second number")
        print( "    " + str(math_dict_binary[op](input_1, input_2)))
    elif op in math_dict_uniary:
        input_1 = get_input("Enter number")
        print( "    " + str(math_dict_uniary[op](input_1)))
    else:
        print("Not a vlaid math option")
        # deal with it
```

Comment: Oh wow, never thought of using dictionaries. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

blank() was used at the end of every case so it can be used at the end of giant if block instead. Also, oneInput is unpythonic for a variable name use one_input. float has many magic methods. They have double underscores before and after the name. Here is a helpful list http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/operator.html. These methods can also be seen by typing `dir(float)`. float was chosen due to division being used.

```
    operators=['+', '-', '*', '/', 'exp'];

    user_operators=[
        getattr(float, '__{}__'.format(i))
        for i in ['add', 'sub', 'mul', 'truediv', 'pow']
    ];

    opl=dict(zip(operators, user_operators));
    output_prompt=' '*7+'> ';

    if op in opl:
        print( output_prompt+str(opl[op](float(input_1), input2)) );
    #--snip-- other conditions for sqrt and log would go here
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported operator {}'.format(op));
    blank();
```

However, if division is removed from the lists operators and operations then int could be used and `float(input_1)` could just be `input_1`.

You may want to save opl[op] as a variable just to name it for easy reading. It is being used like a function.

Comment: Oh so we add an exception handler as well? Seems fancy, i will try it out ASAP :) thanks for the answer :)